Python scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment - How to assign workers to jobs
How do I use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment to assign workers to jobs?
Suppose I have 10 workers and 3 jobs (j1, j2, j3).
My workers have varying skills and I have created a table if they can work on a job.



Worker
j1
j2
j3




1
Y
Y
Y


2
Y
Y
Y


3
Y
Y
Y


4
Y
Y
Y


5
Y
Y
Y


6
Y
Y
Y


7
Y
Y
Y


8
N
N
Y


9
Y
N
N


10
Y
N
N



j1 requires 3 workers, j2 requires 3 workers, j3requires 4 workers.
From the table there are multiple permutations that will work as most of the workforce are multiskilled, but I am only after one.
I have used scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment
If they aren't able to do the job then I've assigned a high cost to try to exclude them.
M = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 99, 99, 1],
              [ 1, 99, 99],
              [ 1, 99, 99],
              ])

row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(M)
print(row_ind, col_ind)

This returns [0 1 2] [0 1 2] which gives me the vector (1,1,1).
I'm not entirely sure if I've done something wrong or am mis-interpreting the results?
Thanks,
Dan

From the docs: "This function can also solve a generalization of the classic assignment problem where the cost matrix is rectangular. If it has more rows than columns, then not every row needs to be assigned to a column, and vice versa." So it won't assign multiple jobs to the same worker.


I'm not entirely sure if I've done something wrong

You didn't include that j1 requires 3 workers, j2 requires 3 workers, j3requires 4 workers in the cost matrix; this can be done easily:
row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(np.repeat(M, (3, 3, 4), 1))

A job requiring n workers here is equivalent to n jobs requiring one worker, so we can repeat each job column so that the number of repetitions amounts to the number of required workers, and by the way we get a balanced assignment problem with your data. The resulting col_ind, for example [9 1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 0], contains the "inflated" job number for each worker in order - 0 1 2 represent j1, 3 4 5 j2, and 6 7 8 9 j3. To reduce this to the original job numbers, we could use e. g.
np.digitize(col_ind, (3, 6, 10))+1 # giving job numbers from 1 on

which returns (with the above example) array([3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]), meaning that j1 is done by workers 2, 9 and 10 (when numbered from 1), and alike for j2 and j3.

Thanks - I kind of get this.
It produces the following output the extra columns are dummy variables?
But then the row and column indicies point some workers to the dummy jobs?
[[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
[99 99 99 99 99 99  1  1  1  1]
[ 1  1  1 99 99 99 99 99 99 99]
[ 1  1  1 99 99 99 99 99 99 99]]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [9 1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 0]

I added explanation to the answer.

As @Armali has already pointed out, you need to encode your "workers per job" information somehow. A more natural way to do that could be to treat your problem as the following maximum flow problem:

Start with a source vertex.
You have 3 job vertices. For each job vertex, there is an edge from the source vertex to the job vertex whose capacity is the number of workers needed for each job, i.e. 3, 3, and 4 respectively.
You have 10 worker vertices. For each job vertex, there is an edge to the worker vertices corresponding to workers that can perform the job. All these edges have capacity 1.
There is a sink vertex. For each worker vertex, there is an edge to the sink vertex with capacity 1.

Your problem is the problem of finding the maximum flow from the source vertex to the sink vertex. For a given solution, you can read off the job-to-worker assignment by reading off the flow from the job-to-worker edges.
Maximum flow solvers are all over the place, but if you want to stick to SciPy, scipy.sparse.csgraph.maximum_flow does the job:
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_array
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import maximum_flow

source = 0
jobs = [1, 2, 3]
workers_required = [3, 3, 4]
workers = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
sink = 14

A = np.zeros((15, 15), dtype=int)
for job, num_workers in zip(jobs, workers_required):
    A[source, job] = num_workers
for job in jobs:
    for worker in workers:
        A[job, worker] = 1
# Remove the unallowed job/worker combinations
A[1, 3+8] = A[2, 3+8] = A[2, 3+9] = A[2, 3+10] = A[3, 3+9] = A[3, 3+10] = 0

for worker in workers:
    A[worker, sink] = 1

result = maximum_flow(csr_array(A), source, sink)

# Check that all jobs are done
assert result.flow_value == sum(workers_required)

# Who does what?
for worker in workers:
    for job in jobs:
        if result.flow[job, worker]:
            print(f'worker {worker-3} does job {job}')

which outputs
worker 1 does job 3
worker 2 does job 3
worker 3 does job 1
worker 4 does job 2
worker 5 does job 2
worker 6 does job 2
worker 7 does job 3
worker 8 does job 3
worker 9 does job 1
worker 10 does job 1

